# how to run browser-sync in laravel

Tags: laravel, gulp, browser-sync

i am new to Laravel and trying to learn gulp. I am trying to use browser-sync  upon running gulp task,browser opens but shows cannot reach.I am not sure if i am using it right way ..

my gulpfile.js

```
var gulp    = require('gulp'),
uglify      = require('gulp-uglify'),
cleanCss    = require('gulp-clean-css'),
rename      = require('gulp-rename'),
sourcemaps  = require('gulp-sourcemaps'),
concat      = require('gulp-concat'),
browserSync = require('browser-sync').create();

gulp.task('browser-sync', function() {

    browserSync.init({
      proxy: 'http://localhost:8000'
    });

  });

gulp.task('default',['browser-sync']);
```

I am using php built in server and is accessible at  http://localhost:8000/
Thank you

Comment: Are you using the `gulp` command or `gulp watch` command? The last one is required to let browser-sync function, otherwise it doesn't know when to refresh your browser with which files since it's not watching your files for changes.

Comment: hi Jhonny, I am using gulp command, when i run command browser-sync is initiaalize and gives url localhost:3000 to access but when i access this url it justs show cannot reach page however project is accessible at http://localhost:8000/  so i think i am having problem in proxy or something.